# Crear un arreglo de objetos JSON con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tengo 3 clases en PHP las cuales uso para extraer información de una base de datos con lo cual me gustaría imprimir o retornar un arreglo con objetos json de todos los estados y sus respectivos países de manera que quedará algo similar a lo siguiente:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "Coahuila",
        "pais":
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nombre": "México"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nombre": "Durango",
        "pais":
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nombre": "México"
        }
    }
]
```

Teniendo en cuenta las clases siguientes.

Clase para la conexión a MySQL

```
    class Conexion {
    private static $conexion;
        private static $server = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba";
        private static $user = "root";
        private static $pass = "";

        public static function conectar() {
        try {
        self::$conexion = new PDO(self::$server, self::$user, self::$pass);
                self::$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        public static function desconectar() {
            try {
                self::$conexion = NULL;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        public static function seleccionar(string $query, array $array = NULL) : PDOStatement {
        try {
                self::conectar();
                $sth = self::$conexion->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
                $sth->execute($array);
                return $sth;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                $e->getMessage();
                return $sth = NULL;
            }
            finally {
                self::desconectar();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Clase para crear objetos Pais

```
    class Pais {

        //Atributos
        private $id;
        private $nombre;

        //Constructores
        public function __construct(){
            $this->id = 0;
            $this->nombre = "";
        }

        public function __destruct() {}

        public function getId() : int {
            return $this->id;
        }

        public function getNombre() : string {
            return $this->nombre;
        }

        public function setId(int $id) {
            $this->id = $id;
        }

        public function setNombre(string $nombre){
            $this->nombre = $nombre;
        }

        //Seleccion de varios objetos
        private static function objetos(string $query, array $array = NULL) : array {
            $sth = Conexion::seleccionar($query, $array);
            if($sth->rowCount() > 0) {
                while($r = $sth->fetchObject()) {
                    $pais = new Pais();
                    if(!is_null($r->id_pais))
                        $pais->setId((int)$r->id_pais);
                    if(!is_null($r->nombre_pais))
                        $pais->setNombre($r->nombre_pais);
                    $datos[] = $pais;
                }
                return $datos;
            }
            else {
                return $datos = NULL;
            }
        }
        public static function todos() : array {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM paises;";
            return Pais::objetos($query);
        }
    }
?>
```

Clase para crear objetos Estado

```
    class Estado {

        //Atributos
        private $id;
        private $nombre;
        private $pais;

        //Constructor
        public function __construct() {
            $this->id = 0;
            $this->nombre = "";
            $this->pais = new Pais();
        }
        //Destructor
        public function __destruct() {}

        //Propiedades
        public function getId():int {
            return $this->id;
        }
        public function setId(int $id){
            $this->id = $id;
        }
        public function getNombre():string {
            return $this->nombre;
        }
        public function setNombre(string $nombre) {
            $this->nombre = $nombre;
        }
        public function getPais():Pais {
            return $this->pais;
        }
        public function setPais(Pais $pais) {
            $this->pais = $pais;
        }

        //Seleccion y guarda paises en un arreglo
        private static function objetos(string $query, array $array = NULL) : array {

            //Obtiene una sentencia que fue preparada y ejecutada en la clase conexion.php
            $sth = Conexion::seleccionar($query, $array);

            if($sth->rowCount() > 0) {
                while($r = $sth->fetchObject()) {
                    $estado = new Estado();
                    if(!is_null($r->id_estado))
                        $estado->setId((int)$r->id_estado);
                    if(!is_null($r->nombre_estado))
                        $estado->setNombre($r->nombre_estado);
                    if(!is_null($r->pais_estado))
                        $estado->setPais(Pais::porId((int)$r->pais_estado)); //Retorna una instancia de la clase Pais con sus atributos
                    $datos[] = $estado;
                }
                return $datos;
            }
            else {
                return $datos = NULL;
            }
        }

        public static function todos() : array {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM estados;";
            return Estado::objetos($query);
        }
    }
?>
```

Saludos

Comment: Cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: Has probado esto? `$sth = mysqli_query("SELECT ...");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);`

Comment: Viendo el JSON que pones al principio creo que en vez de dos consultas por separado puedes lanzar una sola que una ambas tablas (supongo que en la tabla `estados` tienes un identificador para indicar a qué país pertenece cada estado). La consulta sería así más o menos: `SELECT e.id, e.estado, p.pais FROM estados e INNER JOIN paises p ON e.id_pais=p.id ORDER BY pais,estado;`  Incluso el JSON se puede simplificar, poniendo los datos de país al mismo nivel de los del estado. No le veo demasiado sentido a tener un objeto anidado solamente para los datos del país.

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar la interfaz JsonSerializable la cual te permite convertir un objecto a json una vez que sea serializado.

Como funciona ?

Tendras que implementarlo en tus clases por ejemplo

```
<?php    

use JsonSerializable

class Estado implements JsonSerializable {
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return ['id' => $this->getId(), 'nombre' => $this->getNombre()];
    }
}
```

Para serializar luego solo hace un json enconde del objecto. Ejemplo

```
print json_encode(new Estado, true)
```

deberia de imprirmir un json algo asi

```
{
   'id': 1,
   'nombre': "Capital"
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude :)

Comment: para mas informacion puedes ver la documentacion http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php